# Why Penrose's conjecture that consciousness is affected by quantum phenomenon too much of a stretch for Hawking

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question

Why did Stephen Hawking feels that Penrose's statement on [quantum consciousness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mind) is too much of a stretch?

This is a classical reductionist argument. Humans are made by atoms, atoms are made by smaller subparticles that are all governed by the law of quantum mechanics. In the light of this, why would it be too much of a stretch to say that all of our daily activities are governed by quantum phenomenon?

Comment: It is impossible for anybody but Hawking to know what Hawking feels. Apart from that, of course, the "quantum mind" concept is unscientific mumbo-jumbo that has absolutely nothing to do with physics.

Comment: Penrose believes there are an exchange of a particular particle in the pyramidal neurons that effects how thoughts are generated...it is too much for me to consume at the moment

Comment: If that is what Penrose believes, then it's time to conclude that Penrose has lost his mind. Given his advanced biological age that would be perfectly possible. Too bad, he used to be a very smart guy.

Comment: It's not *too* much of a stretch to think that you can't model how the mind works with classical methods CuriousOne is it? That being said I don't think QM wouldd be the full story either, just a way better model than classical ones.

Comment: @CuriousOne Penrose has had various of these weird hypotheses about the brain over the years. I believe he remains an extremely smart guy, but he's fallen prey to the [Lucas argument](http://www.iep.utm.edu/lp-argue/) (a logical fallacy if ever there was one) and needs his equivalent of Descartes' [pineal gland](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pineal-gland/) to make his world-view consistent.

Comment: @Skyler: As far as computational domains are concerned, quantum and classical computing are equivalent. The only difference is that a quantum computer requires fewer "visible" parts (and we don't know how many invisible parts it has, because we do not understand the quantum structure of spacetime, yet). The history of the "quantum mind" is, by the way, based on a misunderstanding. The original proposals were talking about classical interference patters of neural excitations, which are similar to single particle quantum effects. From there the "field" evolved into musical chairs.

Comment: @Nathaniel: Old scientists becoming weird like any other old people is a sad side-effect of biological aging. I have MRI scans of my own brain. Neurons are disappearing with age and liquid filled gaps are opening up. Biology doesn't care who we were when we were 30, by the time we hit 60 or 70, our brains have visibly changed. That is a perfectly classical effect, no QM needed. Beyond that, I am not surprised that Penrose has issues with Goedel's discovery... it probably undermines his belief in his own mathematical omniscience, which, of course, is now provably impossible. :-)